# CPU not being the host in the PCIe bus

Tags: pci-express, hosts

Is it possible to force the CPU as not being the "host" of the system?
But instead a PCIe "device" being the host and contro

Comment: I am pretty sure not.  The CPU must run the computer and be in control.  The PCIe system is attached to the CPU and runs from that.

Comment: Not permanently nor with full control.  The CPU can grant a co-processor or a bus master limited control of system resources, primarily access to main memory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This concept is called *[bus mastering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bus_mastering)* and PCIe supports it.

*Bus arbitration* is the concept of all nodes on the bus adopting some scheme to avoid stepping over each other (the CPU would be or have one of these nodes).

[Read this](https://arstechnica.com/features/2004/07/pcie/) - I think this provides the details on how bus mastering/arbitration works with PCIe.

Comment: This is misleading, the CPU is not a *"node"* and is separate from a PCIe bus, and therefore not subject to bus arbitration.  Maybe you're conflating bus arbitration with memory  arbitration?

Comment: It actually seems possible. Think about a scenario with multiple CPUs in different boards.
I found this company solving this problem with some switching technology: https://dolphinics.com/download/WHITEPAPERS/Dolphin_Express_IX_Peer_to_Peer_whitepaper.pdf

Comment: I could be wrong.  This seemed to be the closest thing to what thr question could mean.  I did think that device-device transfers were possible in PCIe without CPU intervention.

Comment: *"I did think that device-device transfers were possible in PCIe without CPU intervention."* -- Such a transfer of data is possible when the CPU initiates it.  A bus-master can be directed by the CPU to perform a specific data transfer, and cannot initiate a transfer on its own w/o CPU directive.  Hence the bus-master has no control over the system other than the PCIe transfer it is told to perform by the CPU.  IOW you exaggerate/overestimate what a bus-master is capable of.  FWIW device-to-device transfers are rarely actually used by an OS because of the complexity of error recovery.

Comment: To be clear I'm describing bus-mastering in a sane world with an OS (i.e. system software executed by the CPU) that manages all the resources of the system (i.e. the hardware).  If you're trying to make a rogue or malicious device with no regard for system stability, then a bus-master may be the implement for such chaos.